# Can this square root of a square be completed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I found this problem asking to complete the square root of a square number. I have found some numbers but at this point I'm stuck.

[image]

I could brute force my way through, looking for numbers between $3163$ (the smallest with an $8$-digit square), and $3199$ which end in $36$ when squared, but I would like to know if there is enough information to complete the diagram.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $3194^2=10201636$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones digit of the square root has to be $4$ or $6$ to make the ones digit of the square be $6$.  Then we know that a number that ends in $06$ will have a square that ends in $36$ so a number that ends in $94$ will, too.  None of $16^2, 26^2, 36^2, 04^2, 14^2, 24^2, 34^2$ end in $36$ so no other bottom two digits will work.  I used the fact that I know the small squares and negating a square root leaves the square unchanged.